# The emotion of beauty

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word for the emotion you you get when you see or hear something beautiful?

There is a certain feeling somewhere between happiness and sadness, a sort of tingling in your stomach. Is there a word or phrase to describe this feeling?

Comment: what has your research revealed?

Comment: do you mean something more like how you feel when you look out at the Grand Canyon ?  Is 'being moved' what you mean as tingling/happy/sad all at once ?

Answer (score 1):

I think a great word for what you describe is **sublime**

It is an adjective and would need to be coupled with something like ***'sublime pleasure'*** or ***'sublime experience'*** or 'sublime view' etc
.. the usual noun forming constructs usint -ity , inity, osity, ness etc get sort of awkward with the word IMO

Definition 2 below, relating to the inspirational qualities is central to the feel for the word IMO, although with heavy doses of "extremely special" and "sensational" ... I do think the word had evolved more in that direction than the dictionary definitions might give it credit for.

> [**sublime** at Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sublime) adjective
>
> 1.
>   elevated or lofty in thought, language, etc.:
>
> *Paradise Lost is sublime poetry.*
>
> 2.
>   **impressing the mind with a sense of grandeur or power; inspiring awe,** veneration, etc.:
>
> *Switzerland has sublime scenery.*
>
> 3.
>   supreme or outstanding:
>
> *a sublime dinner.*
>
> 4.
>   complete; absolute; utter:
>
> *sublime stupidity.*

Comment: Is "sublime" an emotion? (I'd say no.)

Comment: @Laurel certainly sublime conveys an emotional reaction as a quality. - similar to 'awesome' or 'terrifying' but related more commonly to emotion upon observing something for it's exquisiteness

Answer (score 0):

If the emotional response is transient, I’d call it **frisson**, especially if the emotional response takes the form a “shiver down the spine”.

> **frisson** *noun* a brief moment of emotional excitement

[Definition of frisson](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frisson)

If the emotion is immersive, overwhelming and exclusively positive, I’d describe it as **ecstasy**.

> **ecstasy** *noun* a state of overwhelming emotion; especially : rapturous delight

[Definition of ecstasy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ecstasy)

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a '**touching**' beauty.

> 1. That affects the feelings or emotions; producing strong emotion; affecting, moving.

[OED - touching , adjective](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/203892?rskey=sq1McF&result=3#eid)

It is difficult to describe the sensation when something or someone really beautiful is viewed. The beauty touches something inside, but what is touched is difficult to define or describe.

'Heart-touching' does not describe it; nor does 'soul-touching'.

It is a sense of accord, a sense of delight, a sense of approval, a sense of wonder, a sense of appreciation.

With myself, it is a matter of admiration of the One who made such beautiful things and a sense of pleasure to be able to view them.

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP is after in terms of how wide or lasting effect they are after .   Touching could apply in some aspects to La Boheme: Musetta's aria: Quando m'en vo , but less app for Rachmaninoff: Piano Concerto no.2   in my opinion .  Also, I'm not sure 'touching' would do something like "The grapes of wrath" sufficient credit(although the OP mentione ~seeing and hearing~ not reading .  Touching is good in many ways though.